# Prob. 9, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Which one of these two improper integrals converges absolutely and which one does not?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals, absolute-convergence

Here are the links to three earlier posts of mine on Prob. 9, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin here on Math SE.

[Prob. 9, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Integration by parts for improper integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382436/prob-9-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-integration-by-parts-for-improper-integrals)

[Prob. 9, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Integration by parts for improper integrals with one infinite limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382471/prob-9-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-integration-by-parts-for-improper-integrals-wit)

[Prob. 9, Chap. 6 in Baby Rudin: Integration by parts for an improper integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382503/prob-9-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-integration-by-parts-for-an-improper-integral)

Now my question is the following.

> Which one of the integrals $\int_0^\infty \frac{ \cos x }{ 1+x } \ \mathrm{d} x$ and $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{ (1+x)^2 } \ \mathrm{d} x$ converges absolutely, and which one does not?

My Attempt:

> For any $b > 0$, and  for all $x \in [0, b]$, the following inequality holds:
>   $$ \left\lvert \frac{ \sin x }{ (1+x)^2 } \right\rvert  \leq \frac{1}{(1+x)^2},  $$
>   which implies (by virtue of Theorem 6.12 (b) in Baby Rudin) that 
>   $$ \int_0^b \left\lvert \frac{ \sin x }{ (1+x)^2 } \right\rvert \ \mathrm{d} x \leq \int_0^b \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} \ \mathrm{d} x = - \frac{1}{1+b} - \left( - \frac{1}{1+0} \right) = 1 - \frac{1}{1+b}; $$
>   moreover, 
>   $$ \lim_{b \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+b} \right) = 1. $$
>   So we can conclude that 
>   $$  \int_0^\infty \left\lvert \frac{ \sin x }{ (1+x)^2 } \right\rvert \ \mathrm{d} x = \lim_{ b \to \infty}  \int_0^b \left\lvert \frac{ \sin x }{ (1+x)^2 } \right\rvert \ \mathrm{d} x \leq 1. $$
>   That is, the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \left\lvert \frac{ \sin x }{ (1+x)^2 } \right\rvert \ \mathrm{d} x $ converges, which is the same as saying that the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{ \sin x }{ (1+x)^2 } \ \mathrm{d} x $ converges absolutely.

Am I right?

If so, then, as suggested by Rudin, the other integral does not converge absolutely.

But how to show this directly?

Comment: Hint: it's comparable to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that on any interval of the form $[(k-1/3)\pi, (k+1/3)\pi]$ (where $k \in \mathbb Z$), we have $|\cos(x)| \geq 1/2$. Therefore the integral

$$\int_0^{\infty}\left|\frac{\cos(x)}{1+x}\right|\ dx$$
is at least as large as
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{(k-1/3)\pi}^{(k+1/3)\pi} \frac{1}{2(1+x)}\ dx$$
As the integrand is monotonically decreasing for positive $x$, it follows that on the interval $[(k-1/3)\pi, (k+1/3)\pi]$ (with $k > 0$) we have
$$\frac{1}{2(1+x)} \geq \frac{1}{2(1 + (k + 1/3)\pi)}$$
and therefore
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{(k-1/3)\pi}^{(k+1/3)\pi} \frac{1}{2(1+x)}\ dx \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{3(1+(k+1/3)\pi)}$$
which diverges by limit comparison with $\sum 1/(3k)$.

Comment: I don't think that comparison test says that the last summation diverges, see [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mo1cilgcim). Its the integral test, which is applicable. That is, $\frac{\pi}{3\left(1+\left(x+\frac{1}{3}\right)\pi\right)}$ never greater than $1/x$ for positive values. Thanks for this lovely answer by the way. +1

Comment: @Silent Compare with $1/(3x)$, not $1/x$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but even with this modification, inequality holds only for finitely many negative integers only. See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B3(1%2B(k%2B1%2F3)%5Cpi)%7D%3E%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3k%7D) (scroll down).

Comment: @Silent Right, but asymptotically the difference is negligible: $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{3(1 + (k+1/3)\pi)}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{3k}\right)} = 1$. So by the limit comparison test, either both series diverge or both series converge. Since we know $\sum \frac{1}{3k}$ diverges, so must the original series. You can compare with $1/(4k)$ if you want term-by-term inequality for all sufficiently large $k$. Similarly, $1/(ck)$ will work for any $c > 3$.

Comment: Edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Your proof of convergence is correct.

To show that (a) does not converge, consider that
$$
\int_0^\infty \left| \frac{\cos x}{1+x}\right| \geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2n\pi}^{2n\pi+\pi/6} \left| \frac{\cos x}{1+x}\right| \geq 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2n\pi}^{2n\pi+\pi/6} \left| \frac{1/2 }{1+x}\right| 
\\ \geq \frac{\pi}{12} \sum_{n=0}\frac{1}{1+x}
$$
and the last sum diverges.