# Prob. 10 (d), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Holder's Inequality for Improper Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Here is the link to my earlier post here on Math SE on Probs. 10 (a), (b), and (c), Chap. 6, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

[Probs. 10 (a), (b), and (c), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Holder's Inequality for Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384521/probs-10-a-b-and-c-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-holders-inequality-for-int)

Now I'll be attempting Prob. 10 (d).

Here are the links to my posts here on Math SE on Probs. 7 and 8, Chap. 6, in Rudin:

[Prob. 7 (a), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: If $f$ is integrable on $[c, 1]$ for every $c>0$, then $\int_0^1 f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = $ . . .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375688/prob-7-a-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-if-f-is-integrable-on-c-1-for-every)

[Prob. 7 (b), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Example of a function such that $\lim_{c \to 0+} \int_c^1 f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ exists but . . .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376963/prob-7-b-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-example-of-a-function-such-that-lim-c-t)

[Prob. 8, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: The Integral Test for Convergence of Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377620/prob-8-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-the-integral-test-for-convergence-of-series)

> Let $p$ and $q$ be positive real numbers such that $1/p + 1/q = 1$.
>
> First, suppose that $f$ and $g$ are bounded function on $[a, b]$ such that $f$ and $g$ are Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to a monotonically increasing function $\alpha$ on $[c, b]$ for every $c \in (a, b)$. Then the Holder's inequality gives 
>   $$ \left\lvert \int_c^b f g \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right\rvert \leq \left( \int_c^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p} \left( \int_c^b \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q}. \tag{0} $$
>
> Now if $f$ and $g$ are also Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\alpha$ on $[a, b]$, then so are $fg$, $\lvert f \rvert^p$, and $\lvert g \rvert^q$, by virtue of Theorem 6.13 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition.

Theorem 6.13:

> If $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ and $g \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$, then
>
> (a) $fg \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$;
>
> (b) $ \lvert f \rvert  \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ and $\left\lvert \int_a^b f \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right\rvert \leq \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert \ \mathrm{d} \alpha$.

Now back to the solution

> Therefore by (a variation of) Prob. 7 (a), Chap. 6, in Rudin, we have 
>   $$ \int_a^b fg \ \mathrm{d} \alpha = \lim_{c \to a+} \int_c^b fg \ \mathrm{d} \alpha, \tag{1} $$
>   $$ \int_a^b  \lvert f \rvert^p  \ \mathrm{d} \alpha = \lim_{c \to a+} \int_c^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha, \tag{2} $$
>   and 
>   $$ \int_a^b  \lvert g \rvert^q  \ \mathrm{d} \alpha = \lim_{c \to a+} \int_c^b \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha. \tag{3} $$
>
> Therefore, 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \left\lvert \int_a^b fg \ \mathrm{d} \alpha  \right\rvert &= \left\lvert  \lim_{c \to a+} \int_c^b fg \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right\rvert \qquad \mbox{ [ using (1) above ] } \\
> &= \lim_{c \to a+} \left\lvert  \int_c^b fg \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right\rvert \qquad \mbox{ [ using the continuity of the map $z \to \lvert z \rvert$ on $\mathbb{C}$ ] }   \\
> &\leq \lim_{c \to a+}  \left[ \left( \int_c^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p} \left( \int_c^b \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} \right] \\
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ using a property of limits along with  (0) above ] }  \\
> &= \lim_{c \to a+}  \left( \int_c^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p} \lim_{c \to a+}   \left( \int_c^b \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} \\
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ using Theorem 4.4 (b) in Rudin ] } \\
> &= \left(  \lim_{ c \to a+} \int_c^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p} \left( \lim_{c \to a+} \int_c^b \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} \\
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ using the continuity of the map $y \mapsto y^r$ on $[0, +\infty)$ for every real $r$ ] } \\
> &= \left( \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p} \left( \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q}. \qquad \mbox{ [ usinb (2) and (3) above ] } 
> \end{align}
> $$

Is what I've done so far correct? If so, then is my proof rigorous enough for Rudin? If not, then where have I fallen short?

In the above chain, we have used the result that the mapping $y \mapsto y^r$ is continuous on $[0, +\infty)$, for any given real number $r$.

How to prove this rigorously (and preferably with the help of only what Rudin has discussed so far), especially when $r$ is irrational?