# Prob. 10 (d), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Holder Inequality for Improper Integrals With Infinite Limits

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Here is the link to my Math SE post on Probs. 10 (a) through (c), Chap. 6, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

[Probs. 10 (a), (b), and (c), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Holder's Inequality for Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384521/probs-10-a-b-and-c-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-holders-inequality-for-int)

Here is the link to my first Math SE post on Prob. 10 (d), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin:

[Prob. 10 (d), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Holder's Inequality for Improper Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384620/prob-10-d-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-holders-inequality-for-improper-integrals)

And, here is the link to my Math SE post on Prob. 8, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin:

[Prob. 8, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: The Integral Test for Convergence of Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377620/prob-8-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-the-integral-test-for-convergence-of-series)

Here I'll be attempting a proof of the Holder's inequality for the improper integrals defined in Prob. 8, Chap. 6, in Rudin.

My Attempt:

> Let $p$ and $q$ be positive real numbers such that $1/p + 1/q = 1$.
>
> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are complex functions which are Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to a monotonically increasing function $\alpha$  on $[a, b]$ for every $b > a$, where $a$ is a fixed real number. Then the holder's inequality gives 
>   $$ \left\lvert \int_a^b f g \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right\rvert \leq \left( \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}  \left( \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q}. \tag{0}  $$
>
> Suppose that the integrals $\int_a^\infty f g \ \mathrm{d} \alpha$,  $\int_a^\infty  \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha $, and $ \int_a^\infty \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha $ all converge.
>
> Then by the definition in Prob. 8, Chap. 6, in Rudin, we have 
>   $$ \int_a^\infty f g \ \mathrm{d} \alpha = \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_a^b f g \ \mathrm{d} \alpha, \tag{1} $$ 
>   $$ \int_a^\infty  \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha = \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_a^b  \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha , \tag{2} $$ 
>   and 
>   $$ \int_a^\infty \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha = \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_a^b  \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha . \tag{3} $$
>
> So,
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \left\lvert  \int_a^\infty f g \ \mathrm{d} \alpha  \right\rvert &= \left\lvert \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_a^b f g \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right\rvert \qquad \mbox{ [ by (1) above ] } \\
> &= \lim_{b \to \infty}  \left\lvert \int_a^b f g \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right\rvert  \qquad \mbox{ [ using the continuity of the map $t \mapsto \lvert t \rvert$ ] } \\
> &\leq \lim_{b \to \infty}  \left[ \left( \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}  \left( \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} \right] \\
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ using (0) and a property of the limits ] } \\
> &= \lim_{b \to \infty}  \left( \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p} \lim_{b \to \infty} \left( \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} \qquad \mbox{ [ by Theorem 4.4 (b) in Rudin ] } \\
> &= \left( \lim_{b \to \infty}   \int_a^b \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}  \left( \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_a^b \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q} \\
> & \ \ \  \mbox{ [ using the continuity of the map $y \mapsto y^r$ for $y \geq 0$, $r$ being a given real number ] } \\
> &= \left( \int_a^\infty  \lvert f \rvert^p \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/p}  \left(  \int_a^\infty  \lvert g \rvert^q \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right)^{1/q}. \qquad \mbox{ [ by (2) and (3) above ] } 
> \end{align}
> $$

Is this proof correct? If so, then is it rigorous enough too for Rudin?

If incorrect, then where?

How to show that the map $y \to y^r$ for $y \geq 0$ is continuous, for any given real number $r$, especially when $r$ is irrational?

Comment: $y^r=\exp (r \ln y)$

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski but so far Rudin has not discussed these functions in a systematic and rigorous manner.